# How to create package including source codes, which compile during installation

Tags: package-management, compiling, deb, source-packages

Is it possible to create a deb package for Ubuntu, which contains source codes and automatically compiles them into executable during its installation?

I haven't found any tutorials for this, only tutorials about "how to compile package from sources", which is quite different thing from what i want. That makes me think, this might not be a good idea.

So, is this possible at all, and if yes, is it a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how `.deb` packages work. They contain pre-compiled software, you can't just make a deb package with source code. I have a suggestion: why don't you make a .tar.gz package containing your source code and a script to compile it? The script should look like this:

`#!/bin/bash`

`# here comes the code to compile your source code, like the usual. Change to fit your needs.`

`./configure`

`make`

`make install`

Comment: Well, ok then. I was just thinking about, i don't know whether the user will have 32bit or 64bit architecture, so let's rather make him compile it.
+ The compile script doesn't keep track of installed software, so you can't easily remove it afterwards.

Comment: If you keep the source code somewhere you can always remove the software with `make uninstall`.